# Java - как запустить программу java в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, windows, javafx, jvm

С какими параметрами можно выполнить программу `java`, так чтобы `java` запустилась в фоновом режиме (я запускаю `java` через свою другую программу на `rust`, не через консоль). Я при этом использую **JavaFX** библиотеку в своем проекте.

Comment: «через свою другую программу на rust» — ну значит разбираться, как в rust запускать фоновые процессы, и java здесь вообще абсолютно ни при чём

Comment: Если нужно запускать Java без консоли, можно использовать `javaw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал `javaw`, вместо `java`, чтобы сделать запуск в фоновом режиме.
Спасибо пользователю Nowhere Man.

Comment: Только стоит иметь в виду, что в каких-нибудь линуксах никакого `javaw` не будет (и здесь мы опять приходим к тому, что вопрос на самом деле не про java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170975/how-to-run-a-java-program-without-a-console @andreymal